# Proving that the group of all roots of unity in a number field is finite cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory

I would be very grateful if someone would check my solution to the following problem.

Let $K$ be a number field (i.e. a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Let $G$ be the group of all roots of unity in $K.$

**Claim.** $G$ is a finite cyclic group.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

By definition $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite and this clearly implies that $G$ is finite.

To show that $G$ is cyclic, we proceed by supposing otherwise.

Let $g \in G$ be an element of maximal order, say $m.$

Since $G$ is not cyclic, there exists some $h \in G\setminus\langle g \rangle.$

Let $s$ be the order of $h.$

Then $s$ does not divide $m,$ otherwise $h^m=1$ and so $h \in \langle g \rangle$ (because $\{1,g,\ldots,g^{m-1}\}$ is the complete set of $m$th roots of unity in $K$).

Therefore the order of $gh$ is equal to lcm$(m,s)$ and this is greater than $m.$

This is a contradiction!

Comment: @GregoryGrant Because they are distinct (since $|g| = m$) and $x^m -1$ has $m$ roots at maximum.

Comment: @Gregory: $G$ is the subset of $K$ consisting of all roots of unity in $K.$ I think you are mistaking $G$ for the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: @user301394 ok i got it

Answer (score 5):

> By definition $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite and this clearly implies that $G$ is finite.

How exactly? I think this is a crucial point to prove, more important than your second part, which is alright yet not specific to the number-field situation.

Comment: Let $[K:Q]=n.$ Then any root of unity in $K$ can be at most a primitive $n$th root of unity. Hence the number of roots of unity in $K$ is finite :)

Comment: Almost but not quite. :-) Try it for a third root of unity. Or easier a fourth.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Any element of $K$ must satisfy a polynomial of degree at most $n.$ In particular, any root of unity in $K$ must be either a first, second, ... or $n$th root of unity. Since there are only finitely many such, the set of all roots of unity in $K$ is finite.

Comment: What you just wrote is not correct! A cube root of unity satisfies an equation of degree $2$.

Comment: Oops! I will try to fix...

Comment: Here is a very heavy-handed proof... Suppose instead $G$ is infinite. Then $G$ contains primitive $n$th roots of unity for arbitrarily large $n$. The degree of a primitive $n$th root of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\phi(n).$ As $\phi(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty,$ it follows that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is not bounded above. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @user301394 yes this works (I suppose you can just use that $\phi(n)$ ends to $\infty$ for $n$ to $\infty$, if not you might argue this too). Very simmilary you could say that for each primitive $n$-th root you have $\phi(n)$ is bounded by $[K:Q]$ and there are only finitely many such $n$.

Answer (score 2):

> $G$ is finite

Indeed, the minimal polynomial equation of every element of $K$ has degree at most $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$. In particular, this applies to the [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) that are the minimal polynomials of elements of $G$. Since the inequality $\phi(x)\le [K:\mathbb{Q}]$ has only finitely many solutions, there are only finitely many possible cyclotomic polynomials that are minimal polynomials of elements of $G$, and so $G$ must be finite.

> $G$ is cyclic

Indeed, by Lagrange's theorem, $G$ is a subgroup of $U_n$, the $n$-th roots of unity, where $n=|G|$. Since $U_n$ is cyclic, so is $G$.